# Resilience of ServiceBusProcessor

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am starting to use Azure Service Bus.  My previous experience with Service Buses, is that you need to do a lot of work to ensure that your processes that are pulling messages off the queue do not stall out, get a broken connection, time out, etc.

I noticed that there is a `ServiceBusClient` class for Azure Service Bus.  And that an instance of that class can give you a `ServiceBusProcessor`.  That allows you to setup a delegate to be called when there is a message to be processed.

But I can't find any documentation on how resilient this connection is.  And how to tell when the connection is in a faulted state (so I can re-create it).

How resilient is `ServiceBusProcessor`?  For example, if my application (running on premises) loses network connectivity for an hour, will I need to recreate my instance of `ServiceBusProcessor`?  And if so, how can I know when it its connection has failed and needs to be recreated?

Comment: To be explicit on your concern about managing connections - the processor is responsible for that and will continue to reconnect in the face of a failure.  Your application is responsible for handling application errors during your processing and understanding patterns of errors that occur over time.   More detail around this part is in the linked question.